# Удаление папок или файлов из android

Tags: android

Поскольку я новичок в этой сфере, облазил весь интернет, и не смог найти решение того как можно было бы **удалить папку или файл по нажатию на кнопку. удаление из памяти устройства**, я не про *data* а там где есть такие папки как *download,Android*, и многие другие...

Получилось что-то такого

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.del_server);{

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/file.mp3";
                File file = new File(filePath);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    file.delete();
                }

            }
        });

}
```

При запуске, Приложение выходит из Троя, когда открывается активити в котором есть этот код.

Что я не так сделал?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно можно

Для этого вам необходимо получить пермишны на запись во внешнее хранилище телефона. Прописать в манифесте

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

И Собственно пример самого удаления (этот код вызывайте в клик лисенере)

```
String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/file.mp3";
File file = new File(filePath);
if (file.exists()) {
   file.delete();
}
```

Вот эта строка нужна для получения корня внешнего хранилища на телефоне

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

Comment: Поскольку я Новичок, я понятия не имею про клик лисенер. Могли бы показать как реализовать это вместе с клик лисенер?

Comment: ну, главный совет - учитесь сами искать ответы, это главный скилл любого программиста, я могу дать совет в каком направлении двигаться, вы ищете, что-то не получается, пишите сюда что у вас не получается, и вам снова дадут совет куда двигаться. это так должно работать. клик листенер - mButton.setOnClickListener() что это такое и как с этим работать - статей в интернете огромное количество

Comment: тут читать невозможно, дополняйте вопрос

Comment: Согласен, дополнил вопрос.

Comment: у вас там лишние скобки. и файл file.mp3 я вам написал ради примера.

Comment: Спасибо за частичный код, и за правильоне направление! В итоге мне пришлось полностью переписать код этого клик лисенера. теперь все работает)))

Comment: Такой вопрос, а как сделать так что бы удалял папку вместе с содержанием! а не только пустую папку...